# Soaking phone motherboard in isopropyl to fix potential corrosion

Tags: repair, motherboard, short-circuit

Is it advisable/safe to soak my phone motherboard in an isopropyl alcohol bath?

I dismantled it after water damage occurred and it now powers on fine but my cell signal isn't consistent.

I was advised to soak the MOBO in a bath of isopropyl to remove any potential corrosion on the antenna/board.

Is this sound advice?

---

Here is the component in question.

[image]

Comment: Isopropyl doesn't remove corrosion as much as it would displace the water inside with something else that dries more quickly. I'd use a makeshift vacuum chamber before I soaked the whole thing in alcohol. Since alcohol is conductive if you are unable to dry out your phone completely something might fry the next time you turn it on (which is why I would also use a vacuum chamber to dry it out if I did soak it in alcohol).

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was just the mobo. If it's just the mobo you could since less nooks and crannies where nothing could dry out. But alcohol still doesn't remove corrosion.

Comment: @Toor do you mean that **water** is conductive?  To my knowledge alcohol isn't (but, I haven't done the experiment).

Comment: I think the alcohol bath only helps to *prevent* corrosion by helping to get the water out -- it's not going to make anything un-corrode.

Comment: I do mean the alcohol is conductive. Contact cleaner manufacturers always list it as conductive. But I just went at looked at some other sources say it's not conductive so I don't know what's up with that. There seems to be conflicting info. I'll just go test it right now. But even if it's not, you don't want it around a live circuit anyways since it's very flammable.

Comment: @Toor Impure alcohol is conductive, because the impurity is mostly water. If you get 99% isopropanol it's sufficiently non-conductive for this kind of thing, though it wouldn't really help.

Comment: I just tested both 99.9% isopropyl alcohol and ethanol and they are conductive. Not like zero ohms, but I could get 1-5 megaohms depending on how I went about it.

Comment: Updated the post with a picture of the board+component.

Comment: Corrosion is a sign of moisture intrusion. You will have to fix that issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Isopropyl alcohol ("IPA") can be used to rinse water from a PCB *before* the board corrodes. The IPA then evaporates quickly. This works much better if you use 99% IPA instead of the "standard" 70% IPA you find in grocery stores. (The 99% is often in grocery stores, too, but is in a smaller container that costs more!)

Once the board is already corroded, IPA won't do much. You could try using IPA and a toothbrush to clean up the corrosion (since it will evaporate before causing more), but I've never had that work very well.

Another thing: Once I used IPA on a cheaply manufactured PCB and it softened the solder mask! Another reason to avoid long soaking.

[Here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11327/4869) is a related answer describing what to do if the board is only recently wet.

Comment: Have you ever had experience with an ethanol bath softening the solder mask? I use ethanol for flux cleaning since it's way more effective than isopropyl but for really old, hard residue I've been tempted to let it soak but never have because I'm uncertain about permeation.

Comment: @Toor I've never tried, so I don't know. In fact, I didn't realize that EtOH was better than IPA for flux removal! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yeah, it's real effective. It's the main ingredient in things advertised specifically as "PCB Flux cleaners". It's super effective. Almost no scrubbing need. Usually agitation is enough unless it's been allowed to sit there for a week and dry out and harden. It just so happens it's also the solvent used in my flux which makes sense. It's a lot more expensive (I assume because something about liquor laws) but it saves a lot of time and hassle and I re-use the bath.

Answer (score 1):

Other thing that people haven't mentioned, if it's an intermittent problem, it might not be an issue with the main board. If it's your antenna, it could be a problem with your flexes or even the chassis of your phone, which you might have caused when you disassembled it. You could try adjusting re-seating the main board and flex connectors and see if it helps.

Comment: What is the MLB?

Comment: Main Logic board (mobo).

Answer (score 1):

This is a small step up from the advice you to put your phone in a bag of rice. Actually, it's probably worse because you get about the same chance of improvement with much more effort.

Corrosion is not usually the problem with a wet piece of electronics. The danger is more that there was power applied to the board while it was wet, causing current to flow in unexpected ways, potentially damaging components. IPA will not fix damaged components.

What it is good for is getting rid of residual water. Isopropyl alcohol evaporates very easily. Therefore any residual water will be evaporated as well as long as the IPA mixes with it. If you go down the IPA route, avoid using the 70% IPA you find in most stores - the remaining 30% is probably water. Look for 90% or higher.

In the end, an IPA soak is probably a waste of time. Just take it straight to a repair shop and find out how much it will cost to fix. The time and effort of trying to remove the motherboard coupled with the small chance of it actually fixing anything make this seem not worth it.